# Content Sliding Under Fixed Header And Footer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am developing an app for the Iphone using javascript,css,html.
How can i make the classic iphone effect where the content of the page (if it does not fit the screen in height) slides under the header and footer!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this renders on the i-phone, but it sounds like you're referring to position:fixed.